# MSI installer custom action identity problem

Tags: c#, windows-installer, identity

I'm creating a custom action that executes a script on a database. The problem is that the connectios uses intergrated security, so when I try to open the connection i get the error: Login Failed for user 'Domain\ComputerName$'.

When i check the identity on the custom action (using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`) I always get "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
but I'm running the installer under my account which has enough privileges on the Database.

How can I run the custom action under the real user runnig the msi file or solve this problem in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a simple solutions for this but maybe it's not suitable for all cases.

If you set the project property of **InstallAllUsers**
To true, the installer runs with **"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"** Account, but if you set it to false it runs with the identity of the user who launches the installer.

Setting it to false worked for me, even that I was installing a Windows Service that runs for all users.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you're going to need to

1. Enable 'impersonation' for the custom action.
2. (On Windows Vista and Windows 7 systems) run the *entire* installation in an 'elevated' context (i.e. 'Run as Administrator').

How you accomplish #1 depends on what you are using to create the installation package. In order to easily deal with #2, I use a bootstrapper (created with [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg)) that is configured to run 'elevated'.

Comment: How i accomplish #1 if i'm working on a VS 2008 install project?

Comment: Well, I'm not certain of this, but a little bit of research leads me to believe that perhaps you can't; at least, not without doing something drastic like manually editing the .msi with Orca.