# Running application from setup project not returning UI culture

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I created a localized wpf apllication. To install the application in the system I used *msi installer* provided by visual studio. Upon completion of the installation i run the application by running the `commit custom action` command. 
In the application I have written the below code to get the current UI Culture

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
string name = ci.Name;
```

My systems current language is in *Spanish*, but on installing the application via the installer it is returning to `en-US` culture but should remain *Spanish*. Once i close the application and run it again using the desktop icon it returns to the correct culture.

Can anyone help why it is returning *en-US* on running application using MSI.

Comment: Whether you see the installer running in _Spanish_ or _English_?

Comment: Installer is in English, but my wpf application is localized. when it runs by the installer then aplication window was opening in English which should be in Spanish

Comment: Why can't you make the installer language to _Spanish_ and give it a try.

Comment: Tried with Spanish installer but still its not working.

Comment: Can any one help regarding it

Answer (score 1):

It's related to this:

[Windows installer using the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM instead of login user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838413/windows-installer-using-the-nt-authority-system-instead-of-login-user)

Custom actions run from Visual Studio setup projects run with the local system account, not with the installing user's credentials. There isn't a good solution to this (see the related link) because there's no good way to start a program from the install as if it was started from the logged on interactive user.

Comment: My application is running under the same account for which i changed the language but it did not work